# How do I resign from a job I just started without offending anyone?

Tags: new-job, ethics, resignation, reputation

I started a new job about a month and a half ago.

From day one I didn't like it and felt that it wasn't for me. Initially, I assumed that I was only feeling that way because it was new to me and very different to what I am used to. I tried to give it a chance but have come to realise that the job really isn't for me, there's not a single aspect that I even find bearable.

I have found a new position back in the industry I was in before (and loved) and I have made the decision to resign.

As much as I dislike my current job, I still don't want to burn any bridges. How do I resign ethically and without offending anyone?

Comment: Be honest. Companies have a trial period for new employees, and so do employees with the company. Whether or not you'll burn bridges depends very much on the professionalism of the company which you do not control.

Answer (score 1):

Just talk to your boss. And don't **too honest**. Just tell him/her that you're not suitable in your current job/position/environment. Tell him/her what you feels about your experience after joining this kind of company and works, that this is not your passion. But, you should prepare an answer if you'll be asked why you applying this job in the first time. And that should be good point to be explained if you don't want offend him/her. Then praise him/her company and wish him/her and the company something good, and that you're not feel sorry for joining the company at all. And something like "See you next time, thank you for the opportunities to work with you".

What about your partner? As what people usually do when they move out, say hello, nothing drama is enough in my opinion. If they ask why, just tell them that you can't work here, will find another opportunity. That's all. You're new, so, they will sure understand.

Answer (score 0):

**If you can not be happy with a job, you can not be good at it.**

Most of the performance in a job or during studies depend on if you are interested in the subject/the field. If you don't like what you are doing you will never reach your full potential. This knows your employer, too. Make him aware of that, tell him that you fear that this job is not a good match for you and resign. Be as professional as you can about it, work your notice period and try to make the transtition as smooth as possible.

If your employer is bitter about it, I would not consider it your fault (given you did everything you have to do).